# Gmail API, cannot remove "SENT" label from email

Tags: gmail-api

I cannot **remove the "SENT" label** from any email.
I used PHP classes but it doesn't matter because it occurs even in [test page of users_messages.modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify).

This is my PHP code:

```
$mods = new Google_Service_Gmail_ModifyMessageRequest();
$mods->setAddLabelIds(['UNREAD']);
$mods->setRemoveLabelIds('SENT');
$message = $gmailService->users_messages->modify($userId, $messageId, $mods);
```

I think it could be a general Gmail API error.

I can remove all the others labels but not "SENT". Try it with the follow "Request body":

```
{
  "removeLabelIds": ["SENT"],
  "addLabelIds": ["UNREAD"]
}
```

I got this ERROR 400 reply from the server:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidArgument",
    "message": "Invalid label: SENT"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid label: SENT"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/eitlfDKeCso/lkXkE-cwUzkJ), there is no way of removing the SENT label in Gmail API.